# Is there a way to search google using multiple sites?

Tags: internet, google-search

Currently I use the `site` keyword to search a specific forum, but I want to be able to do this in 2 forums in the same search result.

Something like:

closest distance sites:www.math.com;www.mathworld.com

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the OR operator in all caps.
See http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136861&rd=1.

For your example, we would enter: `closest distance site:mathworld.com OR site:www.math.com`